# Best way to return a string from a controller to ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an action that returns me a single string value:

```
def delay_calulation()
  dr = Dr.find(params[:id])
  delay = dr.calc()

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {"value" => delay}}
  end
end
```

but I a "fail" in my ajax call:

```
$("#btn_delay").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script",
      url: "/drs/delay_calulation/1"
    })
    .done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

  });
```

How can I get a single string, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass id to the controller action while calling through Ajax. You can retrive the string by using the key name that you have mentioned in the controller.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/drs/delay_calulation',
            data: {id: (you need to pass the id)},
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                       var a = data["delay"]
            },
            failure: function(data){
                var a = data["delay"]
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you know a way to pass this "1" parameter as a data like: data {id: 1} ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any number of  parameters in key and value format separated by commas inside the hash. Example.  data: {id: 1}

Comment: If I do this, it calls the "show" action instead of "delay_calculation" action.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Remove the id from the url

Comment: Solved. It was the order of declaration in routes file. thanks.